# Stream My Desktop Screen Make it Accessible via URL?

Tags: video, video-streaming, streaming

I want to stream my desktop screen and convert it into shareable URL format So multiple user can see my desktop video streaming using this link. any suggestion or tools ?

Comment: This is a complex problem and I think you probably need to clarify it. What kind of protocol is required, as video streaming usually adopts RTMP or RTSP, or you may want a web page presented by a browser? What is the desktop platform, since optimized screen capture methods could be quite different on Linux and Windows?

Comment: I think RTSP is fits in my requirement but I will manage if it is in HDL or HLS. I want to stream my windows 10 desktop into web page.

Comment: I have bookmarked a project on GitHub which supports streaming desktop via RTSP or RTMP on windows: [DesktopSharing](https://github.com/PHZ76/DesktopSharing) . However, the description of this repository is in Chinese. There are probably some other projects implement the same function could be found on Github.

Comment: But I want URL of that streaming. which i want to show in browser or share with multiple users.